# read data from serialport

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am new to C# and programming in general.

I am trying to communicate with a ohmmeter which is conneted via usb to my computer.

I am able to configurate the device and even recieve data.
But i can not acces this data. I can just print it on to the console.
(Was inspired by the code on the microsoft site)

Here is the constructer of my "communication"-class where i configurate the port:

```
public SCPI_Commands()
    {
        _SerialPort.PortName = SetPortName(_SerialPort.PortName);
        _SerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
        _SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        _SerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _SerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _SerialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _SerialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
        _SerialPort.Open();
        _SerialPort.DataReceived += _serialPort_DataReceived;
    }
```

Here is my function which sends a query to the device (The constant Measurment_Value represents a scpi command which is understood by my ohmmeter) :

```
public void get_measurement()
    {
        _SerialPort.WriteLine(Measurment_Value);
    }
```

And here is the private function which checks if the device is sending data and printing it on the console (not sure how this function works) :

```
private void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_SerialPort.ReadLine());
    }
```

Unfortunately i am not able to return the data as a string. My goal is to do some calculations with the received data.
Does someone has any ideas ?

Greetings from Germany.

Luke

Comment: I have worked with a Serial Port some time ago.....the code is at home on my pc but I remember that I didn't send and receive strings, I used Bytes for this. If you don't have a valid answer 'til late today I'm going to upload my approach

Comment: What happens with the result of your calculations? If its a short calculation you can perform it in the event handler. If its something long lasting, you may start a thread. BTW: you neither cannot rely on the `DataReceived` event nor `BytesToRead` property. If you want to do more serial port work in the future I suggest to read this [this](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport) and especial the comments.

Answer (score 5):

You can read from buffer to temp byte array and then get it as string, see the below example. Put this in `_serialPort_DataReceived`

```
    // this the read buffer
    byte[] buff = new byte[9600];
    int readByteCount = _serialPort.BaseStream.Read(buff, 0, _serialPort.BytesToRead);
    // you can specify other encodings, or use default
    string response = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff);
```

**Side Note**

If you want to keep your sanity while working with SerialPort, always send and receive as byte array. Then, get the equivalent string using `Encoding`.